# Cannot insert data into database MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem in my code I try to insert my data to database phpmyadmin,when I click submit button, and i got notices an Undefined Index...this is my code :

This is for PHP:

```
    <?php
require_once("koneksi.php");

    $NIP_KARYAWAN = "";
    $NAMA_KARYAWAN = "";
    $LEVEL = "";
    $USERNAME = "";
    $PASSWORD = "";

    if(isset($_POST["simpan"]))
    {
        $NIP_KARYAWAN = $_POST["NIP_KARYAWAN"];
        $NAMA_KARYAWAN = $_POST["NAMA_KARYAWAN"];
        $LEVEL = $_POST["LEVEL"];
        $USERNAME = $_POST["USERNAME"];
        $PASSWORD = $_POST["PASSWORD"];

            $query = "insert into karyawan (NIP_KARYAWAN,NAMA_KARYAWAN,LEVEL,USERNAME,PASSWORD) values ('$NIP_KARYAWAN','$NAMA_KARYAWAN','$LEVEL','$USERNAME','$PASSWORD')";
            mysql_query($query);

            ?><script>alert('Data berhasil ditambah');</script><?php
            ?><script>document.location.href='karyawan.php';</script><?php
            die(0);
    }
?>
```

and then this is my HTML :

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <form role="form" action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="NIP_KARYAWAN">NIP</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan NIP" id="NIP_KARYAWAN" name="NIP_KARYAWAN" value="<?php echo $NIP_KARYAWAN; ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="NAMA_KARYAWAN">Nama</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Nama" id="NAMA_KARYAWAN" name="NAMA_KARYAWAN" value="<?php echo $NAMA_KARYAWAN; ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="LEVEL">Level</label>
                            <select class="form-control" type="text" id="LEVEL" name="LEVEL" value="<?php echo $LEVEL; ?>">
                                <option>Manajerial</option>
                                <option>Operasional</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <form role="form" action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="USERNAME">Username</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Username" id="USERNAME" name="USERNAME" value="<?php echo $USERNAME; ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="PASSWORD">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Password" id="PASSWORD" name="PASSWORD" value="<?php echo $PASSWORD; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">
                <form role="form" action="" method="post">
                    <button id="demo-1" type="submit" name="simpan" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save fa-lg"></i> Simpan</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                    <button id="demo-2" type="submit" name="ubah" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg"></i> Ubah</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                    <button id="demo-3" type="submit" name="hapus" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-dropbox fa-lg"></i> Hapus</button>
                </form>
                </div>                    
            </div>
```

This are the notices :

> Notice: Undefined index: NIP_KARYAWAN in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pencatatan\karyawan.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Undefined index: NAMA_KARYAWAN in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pencatatan\karyawan.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Undefined index: LEVEL in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pencatatan\karyawan.php on line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined index: USERNAME in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pencatatan\karyawan.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined index: PASSWORD in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pencatatan\karyawan.php on line 17

Comment: Please paste the error which notified you of an `Undefined Index` into your question.

Comment: i've edited my question @skrilled

Comment: You have multiple forms on that page.  Only one will actually post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: The form with the submit button(s) doesn't have any of the values you're looking for.  The form(s) with [some of] the values you're looking for don't have submit buttons.

Comment: sorry, i did not know that @PatrickQ

Comment: thank you for your help and explanations :) @David

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The `mysql_*` functions in PHP are deprecated and shouldn't be used. Please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for information on why and what to replace them with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@PatrickQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505169/patrick-q) stated, you have multiple forms. The *submit* buttons are in their own form separate from the form with your expected values. You need to wrap your entire form (and all its respective `input`'s and such) in a single `<form>...</form>`. Buttons and all.

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="NIP_KARYAWAN">NIP</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan NIP" id="NIP_KARYAWAN" name="NIP_KARYAWAN" value="<?php echo $NIP_KARYAWAN; ?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="NAMA_KARYAWAN">Nama</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Nama" id="NAMA_KARYAWAN" name="NAMA_KARYAWAN" value="<?php echo $NAMA_KARYAWAN; ?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="LEVEL">Level</label>
                <select class="form-control" type="text" id="LEVEL" name="LEVEL" value="<?php echo $LEVEL; ?>">
                    <option>Manajerial</option>
                    <option>Operasional</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="USERNAME">Username</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Username" id="USERNAME" name="USERNAME" value="<?php echo $USERNAME; ?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="PASSWORD">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Password" id="PASSWORD" name="PASSWORD" value="<?php echo $PASSWORD; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">
            <button id="demo-1" type="submit" name="simpan" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save fa-lg"></i> Simpan</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <button id="demo-2" type="submit" name="ubah" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg"></i> Ubah</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <button id="demo-3" type="submit" name="hapus" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-dropbox fa-lg"></i> Hapus</button>
        </div>                    
    </div>
</form>
```